# Извлечение данных из строки и передача их в ассемблер

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Полный новичок. Изучаю ассемблерную вставку. Было дано задание: Разработка программы «Вычисление арифметической функции, заданной в текстовом файле».

1. Для реализации программы использовать вычислительные средства архитектуры IA-32.
2. Входные данные, предназначенные для вычисления, задаются в отдельном текстовом файле.
3. Выходные данные, получаемые в результате работы программы, заносятся в отдельный файл.
4. Для ввода и вывода информации в программу использовать операторы языка высокого уровня.
5. Основные операции алгоритма программы должны быть реализованы на ассемблере.

Всё что я смог сделать по этой теме приведено ниже. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y, z, c;
    char s1[255], s2[255]; //Строки
    ifstream in("D:/1.txt"); //Открываем файл для считывания информации 
    in >> s1; //считываем строку
    x = sizeof(s1);
    in.close(); // Закрываем файл

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++) //Ограничение до количества элементов в строке.
    {
    //Как то

      _asm{

      ///Что то

      } 
    }
    
    cout << s1;  //Предварительно выводим значение s1 на экран 

    ofstream out("D:/2.txt"); // Открываем файл для записи
    out << s1 << "\n"; //Записываем первую строчку
    out.close(); //Закрываем файл
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Основная проблема заключается в том, что я не умею извлекать данные из строки.
Предположим char s1[255] = "100+12-11*6". Чтобы посчитать это на ассемблере мне нужно как то получить эти данные и присвоить int ам. А так же как то сделать условие по знакам. С чем собственно и прошу помочь.

Comment: Главное при использовании ассемблерных вставок - не использовать ассемблерные вставки. Делайте полноценную единицу трансляции на ассемблере.